# それにしてもEven for or anyway?

Tags: translation, meaning

The sentence goes

> " **それにしても**お前...ひでぇ面してるぞ"

I read it as " anyway you're...looking terrible" but in the translated manga it says  "even for you, you're face looks terrible"  which one seems more accurate?

Answer (score 5):

> 「それにしてもお前{まえ}...ひでぇ面{つら}してるぞ」

Your translation looks better than the other one as 「それにしても」 means "**at any rate**", "**but still**", etc.  Another translation that should often work well would be "**be that as it may**".

The other person's TL "**Even for you**, your face looks terrible." does not make much sense even in English.

I simply could not think of a context/situation where 「それにしても」 can mean "even for you".

Comment: "Even for you, your face looks terrible" is actually perfectly natural English. It implies that the person's face normally looks bad, but that today it is looking even worse than usual.

Comment: But you'd agree that it doesn't fit in this instance?

Comment: @Noa Yes, I agree with you and l'electeur. それにしても does not mean 'even for you'.